# Not able to pre-populate a form in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, scope

I am a newbie in angular and facing a problem of prepopulating a form using an object.
For example , i have

> 1. Page A have a with form for new employee information .
> 2. Page B displays list of all existing employees information in tabular form and when user clicks on any employee row i redirect to
>      Page A with pre-populated form fields for editing.
>      
>    Both pages use the same controller.

```
<form name="empForm">
        <div style="margin: 21px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <label style="margin-right: 36px;">Employee Name:</label> <input
                type="text" class="text-width text-color" ng-model="emp.fName"
                placeholder="Employee Name">
        </div>
        <div align="center">
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submitCorePack(emp)">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

When filling up the information and submitting the form i get the information in 
emp object and i am able to fetch all information from that object. On page B i display list of registered employees like

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employeelist" ng-click="viewEmployee(employee)">
                    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.fName}}</td>                                                             
                </tr>
```

and when user clicks on any row i pass the employee object to a function which does the page redirecting and form field pre-populating.

```
                        $scope.viewEmployee=function(employee){
                            $scope.emp.fName=employee.fName;
                            $scope.go(); // Redirect to Page A
                        }
```

But i get `$scope.emp.fName` **undefined**, how to solve this problem , how to get this form field populated , please help.

Comment: have you binded the table to same controller  ? @ page B you need to update the second table code or all this code in to a plunker ... .

Comment: can you share your whole controller code since you are sharing the same controller, i might be able to help you.

Comment: @N.V.Prasad yes the controller is same for page B

Comment: Like Alex Said can you share your whole controller code since you are sharing the same controller,

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked Thanks for the help, but the the code i written is sample simulating the actual code the main controller is quite big and have due to employer policies i wont be able to share the actual code :(

Comment: @N.V.Prasad Thanks prasad,please see the above comment the same i told to Alex.

Comment: Code Updation helps for fixing the Issue .. as a new bee  some mistake would roll .. there were few options without lookin at code let me post an answer you need to experiment with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With the code you Provided it is bit hard to guess and fix the issue so iam just posting some Quick options
>
> Inject $rootScope to Controller .    Change
> your code to

```
$scope.viewEmployee=function(employee){
         $rootScope.emp=employee;//Save whole obj where you can play with that.              $scope.go(); // Redirect to Page A
                                       }
```

> Or  **Option2 :- WindowslocalStorage**

`window.localStorage.employee = employee; // check it in developer Tools --> resources -->LocalStorage(click on your Domain)`

> Or  **Option3 :- install local storage Plugin**  :-

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

inject to the controller ,

```
  $localStorageProvider.get('MyKey');
  $localStorageProvider.set('MyKey', { k: 'value' });
```

Comment: For now i have gone with **option 1** , its working thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

U must define $scope.emp:

```
 $scope.viewEmployee=function(employee){
      $scope.emp = employee;
      $scope.go(); // Redirect to Page A
 }
```

Or:

```
$scope.emp = {};
$scope.viewEmployee=function(employee){
      $scope.emp.fName=employee.fName;
      $scope.go(); // Redirect to Page A
}
```